# Convert image into array of pixels

Tags: c++, image-processing, arduino, screen, pixel

I'm trying to display a battery icon on my Arduino LED screen. For that I need pixel level array (matrix) of that icon. Is there any way or tool where I can upload the image then it gives me the pixel representation of that image?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know how to set a single pixel in the LCD screen and have a linux shell access, I can think in a way to hard code the image in your Arduino source. Although this approach is not so practical, it is certainly feasible and fun. So, lets do it!

Suppose you want to display this icon [image: Nuclear icon] named as `nuclear.png`.

By using the `convert` tool from the [ImageMagick package](http://www.imagemagick.org/) you can obtain a text file that lists each pixel in the image through this command:

```
convert nuclear.png nuclear.txt
```

The command above has as output the file `nuclear.txt` below:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 16,16,255,rgba
0,0: (255,255,255,0)  #FFFFFF00  rgba(255,255,255,0)
1,0: (6,6,6,0.556863)  #0606068E  rgba(6,6,6,0.556863)
2,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
3,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
4,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
5,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
6,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
7,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
8,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
9,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
10,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
11,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
12,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
13,0: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
14,0: (6,6,6,0.556863)  #0606068E  rgba(6,6,6,0.556863)
15,0: (255,255,255,0)  #FFFFFF00  rgba(255,255,255,0)
0,1: (6,6,6,0.556863)  #0606068E  rgba(6,6,6,0.556863)
1,1: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
2,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
3,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
4,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
5,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
6,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
7,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
8,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
9,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
10,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
11,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
12,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
13,1: (26,26,26,1)  #1A1A1A  rgba(26,26,26,1)
14,1: (6,6,6,0.94902)  #060606F2  rgba(6,6,6,0.94902)
15,1: (6,6,6,0.556863)  #0606068E  rgba(6,6,6,0.556863)
0,2: (5,5,5,0.94902)  #050505F2  rgba(5,5,5,0.94902)
1,2: (25,25,25,1)  #191919  rgba(25,25,25,1)
2,2: (15,15,15,1)  #0F0F0F  rgba(15,15,15,1)
3,2: (15,15,15,1)  #0F0F0F  rgba(15,15,15,1)
4,2: (17,17,15,1)  #11110F  rgba(17,17,15,1)
5,2: (15,15,15,1)  #0F0F0F  rgba(15,15,15,1)
6,2: (15,15,15,1)  #0F0F0F  rgba(15,15,15,1)
7,2: (15,15,15,1)  #0F0F0F  rgba(15,15,15,1)
8,2: (15,15,15,1)  #0F0F0F  rgba(15,15,15,1)
9,2: (15,15,15,1)  #0F0F0F  rgba(15,15,15,1)
10,2: (15,15,15,1)  #0F0F0F  rgba(15,15,15,1)
11,2: (17,17,15,1)  #11110F  rgba(17,17,15,1)
12,2: (15,15,15,1)  #0F0F0F  rgba(15,15,15,1)
13,2: (15,15,15,1)  #0F0F0F  rgba(15,15,15,1)
14,2: (25,25,25,1)  #191919  rgba(25,25,25,1)
15,2: (5,5,5,0.94902)  #050505F2  rgba(5,5,5,0.94902)
0,3: (5,5,5,0.94902)  #050505F2  rgba(5,5,5,0.94902)
1,3: (14,14,14,1)  #0E0E0E  rgba(14,14,14,1)
2,3: (14,14,14,1)  #0E0E0E  rgba(14,14,14,1)
3,3: (30,26,14,1)  #1E1A0E  rgba(30,26,14,1)
4,3: (181,133,13,1)  #B5850D  rgba(181,133,13,1)
5,3: (32,29,14,1)  #201D0E  rgba(32,29,14,1)
6,3: (14,14,14,1)  #0E0E0E  rgba(14,14,14,1)
7,3: (14,14,14,1)  #0E0E0E  rgba(14,14,14,1)
8,3: (14,14,14,1)  #0E0E0E  rgba(14,14,14,1)
9,3: (14,14,14,1)  #0E0E0E  rgba(14,14,14,1)
10,3: (30,26,14,1)  #1E1A0E  rgba(30,26,14,1)
11,3: (171,125,13,1)  #AB7D0D  rgba(171,125,13,1)
12,3: (26,23,14,1)  #1A170E  rgba(26,23,14,1)
13,3: (14,14,14,1)  #0E0E0E  rgba(14,14,14,1)
14,3: (14,14,14,1)  #0E0E0E  rgba(14,14,14,1)
15,3: (5,5,5,0.94902)  #050505F2  rgba(5,5,5,0.94902)
0,4: (4,4,4,0.94902)  #040404F2  rgba(4,4,4,0.94902)
1,4: (13,13,13,1)  #0D0D0D  rgba(13,13,13,1)
2,4: (19,18,13,1)  #13120D  rgba(19,18,13,1)
3,4: (184,134,13,1)  #B8860D  rgba(184,134,13,1)
4,4: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
5,4: (163,119,13,1)  #A3770D  rgba(163,119,13,1)
6,4: (14,14,13,1)  #0E0E0D  rgba(14,14,13,1)
7,4: (13,13,13,1)  #0D0D0D  rgba(13,13,13,1)
8,4: (13,13,13,1)  #0D0D0D  rgba(13,13,13,1)
9,4: (14,14,13,1)  #0E0E0D  rgba(14,14,13,1)
10,4: (151,112,13,1)  #97700D  rgba(151,112,13,1)
11,4: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
12,4: (170,124,13,1)  #AA7C0D  rgba(170,124,13,1)
13,4: (16,16,13,1)  #10100D  rgba(16,16,13,1)
14,4: (13,13,13,1)  #0D0D0D  rgba(13,13,13,1)
15,4: (4,4,4,0.94902)  #040404F2  rgba(4,4,4,0.94902)
0,5: (4,4,4,0.94902)  #040404F2  rgba(4,4,4,0.94902)
1,5: (12,12,12,1)  #0C0C0C  rgba(12,12,12,1)
2,5: (84,65,13,1)  #54410D  rgba(84,65,13,1)
3,5: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
4,5: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
5,5: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
6,5: (72,56,12,1)  #48380C  rgba(72,56,12,1)
7,5: (12,12,12,1)  #0C0C0C  rgba(12,12,12,1)
8,5: (12,12,12,1)  #0C0C0C  rgba(12,12,12,1)
9,5: (65,51,12,1)  #41330C  rgba(65,51,12,1)
10,5: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
11,5: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
12,5: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
13,5: (72,56,12,1)  #48380C  rgba(72,56,12,1)
14,5: (12,12,12,1)  #0C0C0C  rgba(12,12,12,1)
15,5: (4,4,4,0.94902)  #040404F2  rgba(4,4,4,0.94902)
0,6: (3,3,3,0.94902)  #030303F2  rgba(3,3,3,0.94902)
1,6: (12,12,12,1)  #0C0C0C  rgba(12,12,12,1)
2,6: (184,133,13,1)  #B8850D  rgba(184,133,13,1)
3,6: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
4,6: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
5,6: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
6,6: (101,74,8,1)  #654A08  rgba(101,74,8,1)
7,6: (5,4,2,1)  #050402  rgba(5,4,2,1)
8,6: (4,4,3,1)  #040403  rgba(4,4,3,1)
9,6: (115,85,8,1)  #735508  rgba(115,85,8,1)
10,6: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
11,6: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
12,6: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
13,6: (164,121,12,1)  #A4790C  rgba(164,121,12,1)
14,6: (12,12,12,1)  #0C0C0C  rgba(12,12,12,1)
15,6: (3,3,3,0.94902)  #030303F2  rgba(3,3,3,0.94902)
0,7: (2,2,2,0.94902)  #020202F2  rgba(2,2,2,0.94902)
1,7: (13,12,10,1)  #0D0C0A  rgba(13,12,10,1)
2,7: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
3,7: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
4,7: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
5,7: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
6,7: (7,6,2,1)  #070602  rgba(7,6,2,1)
7,7: (188,136,11,1)  #BC880B  rgba(188,136,11,1)
8,7: (179,128,11,1)  #B3800B  rgba(179,128,11,1)
9,7: (7,6,2,1)  #070602  rgba(7,6,2,1)
10,7: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
11,7: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
12,7: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
13,7: (218,156,13,1)  #DA9C0D  rgba(218,156,13,1)
14,7: (10,10,10,1)  #0A0A0A  rgba(10,10,10,1)
15,7: (2,2,2,0.94902)  #020202F2  rgba(2,2,2,0.94902)
0,8: (2,2,2,0.94902)  #020202F2  rgba(2,2,2,0.94902)
1,8: (9,9,9,1)  #090909  rgba(9,9,9,1)
2,8: (9,9,9,1)  #090909  rgba(9,9,9,1)
3,8: (9,9,9,1)  #090909  rgba(9,9,9,1)
4,8: (9,9,9,1)  #090909  rgba(9,9,9,1)
5,8: (9,9,9,1)  #090909  rgba(9,9,9,1)
6,8: (3,3,2,1)  #030302  rgba(3,3,2,1)
7,8: (188,136,11,1)  #BC880B  rgba(188,136,11,1)
8,8: (184,133,11,1)  #B8850B  rgba(184,133,11,1)
9,8: (4,3,2,1)  #040302  rgba(4,3,2,1)
10,8: (9,9,9,1)  #090909  rgba(9,9,9,1)
11,8: (9,9,9,1)  #090909  rgba(9,9,9,1)
12,8: (9,9,9,1)  #090909  rgba(9,9,9,1)
13,8: (9,9,9,1)  #090909  rgba(9,9,9,1)
14,8: (9,9,9,1)  #090909  rgba(9,9,9,1)
15,8: (2,2,2,0.94902)  #020202F2  rgba(2,2,2,0.94902)
0,9: (2,2,2,0.94902)  #020202F2  rgba(2,2,2,0.94902)
1,9: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
2,9: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
3,9: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
4,9: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
5,9: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
6,9: (7,6,5,1)  #070605  rgba(7,6,5,1)
7,9: (5,4,2,1)  #050402  rgba(5,4,2,1)
8,9: (5,4,2,1)  #050402  rgba(5,4,2,1)
9,9: (7,7,6,1)  #070706  rgba(7,7,6,1)
10,9: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
11,9: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
12,9: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
13,9: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
14,9: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
15,9: (2,2,2,0.94902)  #020202F2  rgba(2,2,2,0.94902)
0,10: (1,1,1,0.94902)  #010101F2  rgba(1,1,1,0.94902)
1,10: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
2,10: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
3,10: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
4,10: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
5,10: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
6,10: (73,56,10,1)  #49380A  rgba(73,56,10,1)
7,10: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
8,10: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
9,10: (79,60,10,1)  #4F3C0A  rgba(79,60,10,1)
10,10: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
11,10: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
12,10: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
13,10: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
14,10: (8,8,8,1)  #080808  rgba(8,8,8,1)
15,10: (1,1,1,0.94902)  #010101F2  rgba(1,1,1,0.94902)
0,11: (1,1,1,0.94902)  #010101F2  rgba(1,1,1,0.94902)
1,11: (7,7,7,1)  #070707  rgba(7,7,7,1)
2,11: (7,7,7,1)  #070707  rgba(7,7,7,1)
3,11: (7,7,7,1)  #070707  rgba(7,7,7,1)
4,11: (7,7,7,1)  #070707  rgba(7,7,7,1)
5,11: (12,11,7,1)  #0C0B07  rgba(12,11,7,1)
6,11: (208,149,12,1)  #D0950C  rgba(208,149,12,1)
7,11: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
8,11: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
9,11: (216,156,13,1)  #D89C0D  rgba(216,156,13,1)
10,11: (17,15,8,1)  #110F08  rgba(17,15,8,1)
11,11: (7,7,7,1)  #070707  rgba(7,7,7,1)
12,11: (7,7,7,1)  #070707  rgba(7,7,7,1)
13,11: (7,7,7,1)  #070707  rgba(7,7,7,1)
14,11: (7,7,7,1)  #070707  rgba(7,7,7,1)
15,11: (1,1,1,0.94902)  #010101F2  rgba(1,1,1,0.94902)
0,12: (1,1,1,0.94902)  #010101F2  rgba(1,1,1,0.94902)
1,12: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
2,12: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
3,12: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
4,12: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
5,12: (84,64,9,1)  #544009  rgba(84,64,9,1)
6,12: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
7,12: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
8,12: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
9,12: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
10,12: (108,80,10,1)  #6C500A  rgba(108,80,10,1)
11,12: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
12,12: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
13,12: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
14,12: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
15,12: (1,1,1,0.94902)  #010101F2  rgba(1,1,1,0.94902)
0,13: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
1,13: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
2,13: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
3,13: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
4,13: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
5,13: (70,53,9,1)  #463509  rgba(70,53,9,1)
6,13: (179,130,12,1)  #B3820C  rgba(179,130,12,1)
7,13: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
8,13: (226,163,13,1)  #E2A30D  rgba(226,163,13,1)
9,13: (175,127,12,1)  #AF7F0C  rgba(175,127,12,1)
10,13: (63,48,8,1)  #3F3008  rgba(63,48,8,1)
11,13: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
12,13: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
13,13: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
14,13: (6,6,6,1)  #060606  rgba(6,6,6,1)
15,13: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
0,14: (0,0,0,0.556863)  #0000008E  rgba(0,0,0,0.556863)
1,14: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
2,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
3,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
4,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
5,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
6,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
7,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
8,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
9,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
10,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
11,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
12,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
13,14: (5,5,5,1)  #050505  rgba(5,5,5,1)
14,14: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
15,14: (0,0,0,0.556863)  #0000008E  rgba(0,0,0,0.556863)
0,15: (255,255,255,0)  #FFFFFF00  rgba(255,255,255,0)
1,15: (0,0,0,0.556863)  #0000008E  rgba(0,0,0,0.556863)
2,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
3,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
4,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
5,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
6,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
7,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
8,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
9,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
10,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
11,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
12,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
13,15: (0,0,0,0.94902)  #000000F2  rgba(0,0,0,0.94902)
14,15: (0,0,0,0.556863)  #0000008E  rgba(0,0,0,0.556863)
15,15: (255,255,255,0)  #FFFFFF00  rgba(255,255,255,0)
```

You can see easily that, except for the first line, each line presents a pixel coordinate followed by the corresponding RGBA color value. You can obtain more information about this format in the [official documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#txt).

By using some piped shell commands over `nuclear.txt`, we can generated a hard-coded array of integers in `nuclear.cpp`:

```
(echo "int pixels[] = {"; \
tail -n +2 nuclear.txt | tr -cs '0-9.\n'  ' ' | \
while read x y r g b junk; do echo "   $x,$y,$r,$g,$b,";done; \
echo "-1};") > nuclear.cpp
```

The `nuclear.cpp` content:

```
int pixels[] = {
   0,0,255,255,255,
   1,0,43,43,43,
   2,0,43,43,43,
   3,0,43,43,43,
   4,0,43,43,43,
   5,0,43,43,43,
   6,0,43,43,43,
   7,0,43,43,43,
   8,0,43,43,43,
   9,0,43,43,43,
   10,0,43,43,43,
   11,0,43,43,43,
   12,0,43,43,43,
   13,0,43,43,43,
   14,0,43,43,43,
   15,0,255,255,255,
   0,1,42,42,42,
   1,1,42,42,42,
   2,1,90,90,90,
   3,1,90,90,90,
   4,1,90,90,90,
   5,1,90,90,90,
   6,1,90,90,90,
   7,1,90,90,90,
   8,1,90,90,90,
   9,1,90,90,90,
   10,1,90,90,90,
   11,1,90,90,90,
   12,1,90,90,90,
   13,1,90,90,90,
   14,1,42,42,42,
   15,1,42,42,42,
   0,2,40,40,40,
   1,2,89,89,89,
   2,2,69,69,69,
   3,2,69,69,69,
   4,2,74,73,69,
   5,2,69,69,69,
   6,2,69,69,69,
   7,2,69,69,69,
   8,2,69,69,69,
   9,2,69,69,69,
   10,2,69,69,69,
   11,2,73,72,69,
   12,2,69,69,69,
   13,2,69,69,69,
   14,2,89,89,89,
   15,2,40,40,40,
   0,3,37,37,37,
   1,3,67,67,67,
   2,3,67,67,67,
   3,3,96,90,66,
   4,3,219,191,64,
   5,3,100,94,66,
   6,3,67,67,67,
   7,3,67,67,67,
   8,3,67,67,67,
   9,3,67,67,67,
   10,3,96,90,66,
   11,3,214,186,64,
   12,3,90,85,66,
   13,3,67,67,67,
   14,3,67,67,67,
   15,3,37,37,37,
   0,4,35,35,35,
   1,4,65,65,65,
   2,4,77,75,65,
   3,4,221,192,63,
   4,4,242,209,63,
   5,4,209,182,63,
   6,4,67,67,65,
   7,4,65,65,65,
   8,4,65,65,65,
   9,4,67,67,65,
   10,4,202,177,63,
   11,4,242,209,63,
   12,4,213,185,63,
   13,4,71,70,65,
   14,4,65,65,65,
   15,4,35,35,35,
   0,5,32,32,32,
   1,5,62,62,62,
   2,5,155,138,63,
   3,5,242,209,63,
   4,5,242,209,63,
   5,5,242,209,63,
   6,5,145,129,62,
   7,5,62,62,62,
   8,5,62,62,62,
   9,5,138,124,62,
   10,5,242,209,63,
   11,5,242,209,63,
   12,5,242,209,63,
   13,5,145,129,62,
   14,5,62,62,62,
   15,5,32,32,32,
   0,6,28,28,28,
   1,6,60,60,60,
   2,6,221,191,63,
   3,6,242,209,63,
   4,6,242,209,63,
   5,6,242,209,63,
   6,6,169,147,49,
   7,6,37,34,25,
   8,6,34,33,26,
   9,6,179,156,51,
   10,6,242,209,63,
   11,6,242,209,63,
   12,6,242,209,63,
   13,6,210,183,62,
   14,6,60,60,60,
   15,6,28,28,28,
   0,7,25,25,25,
   1,7,64,62,57,
   2,7,242,209,63,
   3,7,242,209,63,
   4,7,242,209,63,
   5,7,242,209,63,
   6,7,46,42,21,
   7,7,223,193,59,
   8,7,218,188,58,
   9,7,46,41,22,
   10,7,242,209,63,
   11,7,242,209,63,
   12,7,242,209,63,
   13,7,238,205,63,
   14,7,57,57,57,
   15,7,25,25,25,
   0,8,22,22,22,
   1,8,54,54,54,
   2,8,54,54,54,
   3,8,54,54,54,
   4,8,54,54,54,
   5,8,54,54,54,
   6,8,29,27,20,
   7,8,223,193,59,
   8,8,221,191,58,
   9,8,32,30,22,
   10,8,54,54,54,
   11,8,54,54,54,
   12,8,54,54,54,
   13,8,54,54,54,
   14,8,54,54,54,
   15,8,22,22,22,
   0,9,18,18,18,
   1,9,51,51,51,
   2,9,51,51,51,
   3,9,51,51,51,
   4,9,51,51,51,
   5,9,51,51,51,
   6,9,45,44,40,
   7,9,38,35,20,
   8,9,37,34,20,
   9,9,47,45,41,
   10,9,51,51,51,
   11,9,51,51,51,
   12,9,51,51,51,
   13,9,51,51,51,
   14,9,51,51,51,
   15,9,18,18,18,
   0,10,15,15,15,
   1,10,48,48,48,
   2,10,48,48,48,
   3,10,48,48,48,
   4,10,48,48,48,
   5,10,48,48,48,
   6,10,146,129,56,
   7,10,242,209,63,
   8,10,242,209,63,
   9,10,151,133,56,
   10,10,48,48,48,
   11,10,48,48,48,
   12,10,48,48,48,
   13,10,48,48,48,
   14,10,48,48,48,
   15,10,15,15,15,
   0,11,12,12,12,
   1,11,46,46,46,
   2,11,46,46,46,
   3,11,46,46,46,
   4,11,46,46,46,
   5,11,62,59,47,
   6,11,233,201,62,
   7,11,242,209,63,
   8,11,242,209,63,
   9,11,237,205,63,
   10,11,74,69,48,
   11,11,46,46,46,
   12,11,46,46,46,
   13,11,46,46,46,
   14,11,46,46,46,
   15,11,12,12,12,
   0,12,9,9,9,
   1,12,43,43,43,
   2,12,43,43,43,
   3,12,43,43,43,
   4,12,43,43,43,
   5,12,155,137,54,
   6,12,242,209,63,
   7,12,242,209,63,
   8,12,242,209,63,
   9,12,242,209,63,
   10,12,174,152,56,
   11,12,43,43,43,
   12,12,43,43,43,
   13,12,43,43,43,
   14,12,43,43,43,
   15,12,9,9,9,
   0,13,6,6,6,
   1,13,41,41,41,
   2,13,41,41,41,
   3,13,41,41,41,
   4,13,43,42,41,
   5,13,143,126,52,
   6,13,218,189,60,
   7,13,242,209,63,
   8,13,242,209,63,
   9,13,216,187,60,
   10,13,136,120,51,
   11,13,43,43,41,
   12,13,41,41,41,
   13,13,41,41,41,
   14,13,41,41,41,
   15,13,6,6,6,
   0,14,4,4,4,
   1,14,4,4,4,
   2,14,39,39,39,
   3,14,39,39,39,
   4,14,39,39,39,
   5,14,39,39,39,
   6,14,39,39,39,
   7,14,39,39,39,
   8,14,39,39,39,
   9,14,39,39,39,
   10,14,39,39,39,
   11,14,39,39,39,
   12,14,39,39,39,
   13,14,39,39,39,
   14,14,4,4,4,
   15,14,4,4,4,
   0,15,255,255,255,
   1,15,2,2,2,
   2,15,2,2,2,
   3,15,2,2,2,
   4,15,2,2,2,
   5,15,2,2,2,
   6,15,2,2,2,
   7,15,2,2,2,
   8,15,2,2,2,
   9,15,2,2,2,
   10,15,2,2,2,
   11,15,2,2,2,
   12,15,2,2,2,
   13,15,2,2,2,
   14,15,2,2,2,
   15,15,255,255,255,
-1};
```

Note that each line of the `pixels` array is formatted as `row,col,r,g,b` and the last element `-1` is included intentionally. Once you have pasted this array in your source code, you can use the snippet below for iterating through pixels and showing them on the screen using a custom function:

```
int i = 0;
while (pixels[i]>-1) {
   int row = pixels[i++];
   int col = pixels[i++];
   int r = pixels[i++];
   int g = pixels[i++];
   int b = pixels[i++];

   //Show the pixel 
   //showPixel(row,col,r,g,b); You need to implement that.
}
```

That's it!

Comment: +1, nice answer. And fancy piped shell command, I'm not familiar with all of the commands, but that looks a little "badass" for the untrained eye, very nice :D But I'm going to look up all of them :)

Comment: You can actually ask ImageMagick to generate a C header file for you... `convert nuclear.png nuclear.h`

Comment: Thank you @MarkusWeninger. I wanted to write that command in one line and it quickly became a little monster =) Be careful!

Comment: @MarkSetchell, great finding! I will take a look into the resulting format.